# R special if- statement over column names

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame and I want to add the units (µg,g,...)to the values of the columnnames. My data is called BLS_datatable. I have added the units seperately with the following code. I know that is a bit redundant, but it works. The value here is KiloJoule.

```
colnames(BLS_datatable) <- gsub(colnames(BLS_datatable), pattern = 'KiloJoule', replacement = 'KiloJoule[kj]')
```

mg is the most common unit in my data frame that consists of more than 100 columns. I want to do a "if statement" for adding the unit mg to the suitable values. Unfortunately, this is not working:

```
if("[" %in% colnames(BLS_datatable)){
  print(colnames(BLS_datatable))
} else {
  print(colnames(c(BLS_datatable),"[mg]"))
}
```

What is wrong here?
Thank you for helping me
,Cheers

Comment: Change `%in%` with `grepl`

Comment: You mentioned that `mg` is the most _common_ unit, but not the only one.  How can we know which unit to assign to which column?

Comment: i have changed the others seperately manually. So I took for example all the µg columns and did the first code snippet with them. All the remaining columns are now with mg

Comment: Thank you Sotos, I do not know what you mean exactly but I tried this and it failed  ``` if (grepl("[",colnames(BLS_datatable) == T){
  print(colnames(BLS_datatable))
} else {
  print(colnames(c(BLS_datatable),"[mg]"))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments after running the first part, remaining of them are the "mg" columns. We can get the column numbers of `"KiloJoule"` columns, `invert` them to get the remaining column numbers and add `'[mg]'` to those columns.

```
inds <- grep('KiloJoule', colnames(BLS_datatable), invert = TRUE)
colnames(BLS_datatable)[inds] <- paste0(colnames(BLS_datatable)[inds], '[mg]')
```

Comment: actually, there are more than the example column KiloJoule that are not in mg. Actually there are about 30 columns with a different unit than mg. I only want to add the [mg] to columns that have not already been changed.   ```inds <- grep('[', colnames(BLS_datatable), invert = T)
colnames(BLS_datatable)[inds] <- paste0(colnames(BLS_datatable)[inds], '[mg]')``` That is unfortunately not working. But I think (or hope) your answer Ronak will bring me to the right path...

Comment: @takeITeasy You first said all the remaining columns are mg after changing "KiloJoule". Now you say they are not. How do you identify `mg` columns then? Why are you looking for `[` in `grep` ? Do you need `inds <- grep('[', colnames(BLS_datatable), invert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)` ?

Comment: With your "answer solution" all the columns, including the ones that have their correct units are added with mg, for example like "KiloJoule[kcal][mg]". I only want the column names that do not already have an unit to be added the [mg]. So all the column names that does not include “[“ should get a [mg]. Thank you for your patience, Ronak Shah

Comment: @takeITeasy Did you try my suggestion? `inds <- grep('[', colnames(BLS_datatable), invert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)` and then `colnames(BLS_datatable)[inds] <- paste0(colnames(BLS_datatable)[inds], '[mg]')` ?

Comment: That is actually working properly. Initially I did not do the last bit correctly. Thank you again. I really appreciate it.